# whats the difference between .communicate() and .communicate()[0]?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I'm using python. I'm trying to run a process and fetch the output using subprocess.popen. After reading around I see people using communicate()[0] but thats not in the docs, it is used in an example. I'm wondering if someone could fill me in as to why one would append [0] to communicate()?

Answer (score 6):

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

```
Popen.communicate(input=None)
```

> Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr,
>   until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to
>   terminate. The optional input argument should be a string to be sent
>   to the child process, or None, if no data should be sent to the child.

`communicate()` returns a **tuple** (stdoutdata, stderrdata).

So `communicate()[0]` is used to access the `stdoutdata` and `communicate()[1]` to access the `stderrdata`

To access elements in a tuple or list we use indexes, first element is at index 0.

```
>>> tup = ("foo", "bar")
>>> tup[0]
'foo'
>>> tup[1]
'bar'
```